# Update records within arrays

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've just started to look at meteor and I'm stuck trying to update a record within an array within a record. Say i have a document that looks something like this:

```
Users:
{ 
  _id: "somerandom",
  name: "name1",
  items, [
    {
      name: "item1",
      data: "somedata",
      ...
    },
    {
      name: "item2",
      data: "somedata",
      ...
    }
  ],
  ...
},
...
```

And I want to update the data of items 'item1'. I can't find anything on how to do this in meteor, but from what I have read about MongoDB I think that the correct way would be something like

```
Users.update({_id: userId, "items.name": 'item1}, {$set: {"items.$.data": newData}});
```

but since the MongoDB used in Meteor doesn't support $ it won't work, on the other hand I might be way of how this should be done.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Meteor.methods()` and implement your database operation on the server side and call it using `Meteor.call()` from the client. This feature is not yet implemented in Meteor and it is documented [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/minimongo/NOTES).

You can read more in the discussion on this issue raised on Github, [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/153).

Comment: I don't really get this. can i use $ selector on the server-side then?

Comment: Yes. That's the workaround suggested according to the discussion or what you suggested below is clean too.

Comment: I can confirm what Prashant is saying.  works fine if i do it in a server method, but not in the client.  sucks, it'd be nice to do it in the client.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround at meteor's github https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/parties/model.js

The idea is to first get the index of the array-item you want to change and then use that index instead of $. So in this case it would be something like

```
user = Users.findOne(userId);
index = _.indexOf(_.pluck(user.items, 'name'), 'item1');

modifier = {$set: {}};
modifier.$set["items." + index + ".data"] = newData;
Users.update(userId, modifier);
```